# Django: How to create custom ModelSerializer from multiple models/tables in mySQL database?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I'm working on a Django project with an already existing mySQL database. I've quickly learned that mySQL lacks the explicit relationships found in postgresSQL databases where you can establish one to one, one to many, many to many relationships. Instead, you typically need to create a whole other table just for relationships.

So currently, I have three tables: userpie_users, radar_sites, and userpie_users2radars (table describing the relationships).

**Table: userpie_users**
[image: userpie_users]

**Table: radar_sites**
[image: radar_sites]

**Table: userpie_users2radars**
[image]

Just to clarify, let's examine the first row of userpie_users2radars:
id: 2, user_id: 78, radar_id: 17

The id: 2 can be ignored but this row specifies that user_id (78) from userpie_users is attached to radar_id(17) from radar_sites. The next row reveals that the same user also is attached to radar_id(4).

For my API "GET" endpoint (http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/map/user_id), I want my final JSON body response to be something like this:

```
    {
    "user_id":"123",
    "last_name":"smith",
    "first_name":"john",
    "last_radar":"28",
    "radars":[["19","Coal Point Reserve UCSB"],["39","Harvey"],["33","Hawaii"]]
}
```

The first four fields are in the userpie_users table so this can be easily serialized with ModelSerializer. "last_radar" is cut off in the screenshot but it's there.

"radars" however is an array I need to make by grabbing the user_id from the url parameters, looking through each row in userpie_users2radars and if the user_id matches, grab the radar_id. I will then have an array of radar_id which I will need to loop through radar_sites table and grab the name of the radar_site (eg. Harvey, Hawaii). Combine the radar_id and the name and put that into an array.

**map/api/views.py**:

```
@api_view(('GET',))
def api_user_radars(request, user_id): 
    try: 
        user_object = UserpieUsers.objects.get(user_id=user_id)
    except UserpieUsers.DoesNotExist: 
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND) 
    
    if request.method == "GET": 
        serializer = UserpieUserstSerializer(user_object)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

**map/api/serializers.py:**

```
class UserpieUserstSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = UserpieUsers
        fields = ['user_id', 'last_name', 'first_name', 'last_radar']
```

**map/api/urls.py:**

```
    urlpatterns = [
    path('<user_id>/', api_user_radars, name="userpie_users")
]
```

What is the best way to create and incorporate the radar array into my JSON body?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To serialize relied model you basically  need to make serializer for relied model and add it as field to your "main" serializer:

```
class RadarSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
     class Meta:
            model = YourRadarModel
            fields = ["id", "name"]

class UserpieUserstSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    #name of this field must be same as name of ManyToMany field  or value of "related_name" in models.py, I called it radars
    radars = RadarSerializer(many=True, read_only=True) 


    class Meta:
        model = UserpieUsers
        fields = ['user_id', 'last_name', 'first_name', 'last_radar', 'radars']
```

This will give you output like that:

```
 {
    "user_id":"123",
    "last_name":"smith",
    "first_name":"john",
    "last_radar":"28",
    "radars":[
              {"id": "19",
               "name": "Coal Point Reserve UCSB"},
              {"id": "39",
               "name": "Harvey"},
               ....
}
```

If getting radars as list of pairs, instead of dict is necessary for you you can do something like:

```
#in models.py

class YourRadarModel(models.Model):
   #...
   #some fields
   @property
   def id_and_name_pair(self):
        return [self.id, self.name]
```

and in serializers:

```
from rest_framework.serializers  RelatedField


class RadarField(serializers.RelatedField):
    def to_representation(self, value):
        return value.id_and_name_pair

class UserpieUserstSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

        radars = RadarField(many=True, read_only=True) 

        class Meta:
            model = UserpieUsers
            fields = ['user_id', 'last_name', 'first_name', 'last_radar', 'radars']
```

Comment: That's a cool trick of putting the RadarSerializer inside the UserpieUserstSerializer. However, where is the logic to check to see all the radar_id of a given user_id in the userpie_users2radars table?

Answer (score 1):

I just wanted to share a more optimized solution based on the one that worked for you:

```
@api_view(('GET',))
def get_user_radars(request, user_id):
    try:
        user = UserpieUsers.objects.get(user_id=user_id)
        user_serializer = UserpieUsersSerializer(user)

        radar_ids = list(UserpieUsers2Radars.objects.filter(
            user_id=user_id).values_list('radar_id', flat=True))
        # radar_ids = [radar.radar_id for radar in radars] you avoid this N+1 queries

        radar_sites = RadarSites.objects.filter(id__in=radar_ids)  # Use "id" to filter radar_sites
        radar_serializer = RadarSitesSerializer(radar_sites, many=True)

        radar_data = [[i['id'], i['name']] for i in radar_serializer.data]

        response_data = {
            'user_id': user_serializer.data['user_id'],
            'last_name': user_serializer.data['last_name'],
            'first_name': user_serializer.data['first_name'],
            'last_radar': user_serializer.data['last_radar'],
            'radars': radar_data,
        }
        return Response(response_data)
    except UserpieUsers.DoesNotExist:
        return Response({'message': 'User not found'}, status=404)
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution!

**serializers.py**

```
class UserpieUsersSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = UserpieUsers
    fields = ['user_id', 'last_name', 'first_name', 'last_radar']

class RadarSitesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = RadarSites
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'status']
```

**views.py**

```
    @api_view(('GET',))
def get_user_radars(request, user_id):
    try:
        user = UserpieUsers.objects.get(user_id=user_id)
        user_serializer = UserpieUsersSerializer(user)

        radars = UserpieUsers2Radars.objects.filter(user_id=user_id)
        radar_ids = [radar.radar_id for radar in radars]

        radar_sites = RadarSites.objects.filter(id__in=radar_ids)  # Use "id" to filter radar_sites
        radar_serializer = RadarSitesSerializer(radar_sites, many=True)

        radar_data = []  # Collect radar data as a list of [id, name] lists
        for radar in radar_serializer.data:
            radar_data.append([radar['id'], radar['name']])

        response_data = {
            'user_id': user_serializer.data['user_id'],
            'last_name': user_serializer.data['last_name'],
            'first_name': user_serializer.data['first_name'],
            'last_radar': user_serializer.data['last_radar'],
            'radars': radar_data,
        }
        return Response(response_data)
    except UserpieUsers.DoesNotExist:
        return Response({'message': 'User not found'}, status=404)
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
path('user/<user_id>/', get_user_radars, name="userpie_users_with_radar")
```

]